# Python: how to create multiple listeners without multithreading?

Tags: python, multithreading, twitter, listener

I am trying to follow the [example here](http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2014/07/twitter-analytics/) but I want more than one listener. How to create multiple listeners without multithreading?

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream

#Variables that contains the user credentials to access Twitter API
access_token = "<...>"
access_token_secret = "<...>"
consumer_key = "<...>"
consumer_secret = "<...>"

#This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print data
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status


if __name__ == '__main__':

    #This handles Twitter authetification and the connection to Twitter Streaming API
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l)

    #This line filter Twitter Streams to capture data by the keywords: 'python', 'javascript', 'ruby'
    stream.filter(track=['python', 'javascript', 'ruby'])

    print "Control never seems to arrive here"

    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l)

    #This line filter Twitter Streams to capture data by the keywords: 'python', 'javascript', 'ruby'
    stream.filter(track=['django', 'angularjs', 'rails'])
```

Stackoverflow wants more text
Stackoverflow wants more text
Stackoverflow wants more text

Answer (score 1):

I have come across the same question here myself. 
My solution to this has been to run different instances of the script within a new command line process. If you do this, you will need to save each "version" of your script as a separate file. 
There is probably a much better solution for this, but it is the best I have right now.

Hope this helps at least a little.

- Az

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it should be even possible to do it multithreaded way but I wonder why I cannot have more than one listener.

Comment: I am spitballing at this point but have you tried setting up multiple filters (unique variable for each) and then matching listeners (unique variable each).

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the `Connections` section of the [streaming API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/public), Twitter only allows you one connection to the streaming endpoint. Too many connection attempt may lead to them banning your IP.

Comment: Thank you, but let's talk about listeners issue, let's leave twitter and their requirements out of scope for the moment.

Comment: But Twitter will automatically disconnect your first connection if you make a second one, that may be part of your problem.

Comment: No, it works when I make one listener per thread with multiple threads.